# one to many with symfony's admin generator

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm using Symfony's 1.4 admin generator, and I have a question about a one to many relationship.
If A has many B and B one A, I will see a listbox when editing B, that's ok, but I have to add a list (with multiple choices) of B when I edit an A.
I have a solution but I don't no if it is the right way : I have modified the A form this way :

```
class AForm extends BaseAForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->widgetSchema['b_list'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 'B'));
    $this->validatorSchema['b_list'] = new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 'B', 'required' => false));
  }

  public function updateDefaultsFromObject()
  {
    parent::updateDefaultsFromObject();

    if (isset($this->widgetSchema['b_list']))
    {
      $this->setDefault('b_list', $this->object->B->getPrimaryKeys());
    }

  }

  protected function doSave($con = null)
  {
    $this->saveBsList($con);

    parent::doSave($con);
  }

  public function saveBsList($con = null)
  {
    if (!$this->isValid())
    {
      throw $this->getErrorSchema();
   }

    if (!isset($this->widgetSchema['b_list']))
    {
      // somebody has unset this widget
      return;
    }

    if (null === $con)
    {
      $con = $this->getConnection();
    }

    $existing = $this->object-Bs->getPrimaryKeys();
    $values = $this->getValue('b_list');
    if (!is_array($values))
    {
      $values = array();
    }

    $unlink = array_diff($existing, $values);
    if (count($unlink))
    {
      $this->object->unlink('Bs', array_values($unlink));
    }

    $link = array_diff($values, $existing);
    if (count($link))
      {
      $this->object->link('Bs', array_values($link));
    }
   }
 }
```

I use the same code which is generated for a many-to-namy relation.
Is there a better way ?

Thanks

Edit :

The schema

```
Agency:
  columns:
    id:
      type:               integer(4)
      primary:            true
      autoincrement:      true
    name:                  { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Consultants:
      refClass:           Consultant

Consultant:
  columns:
    if:
      type:               integer(4)
      primary:            true
      autoincrement:      true
    name:                  { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    ref_agency:           integer(4)
  relations:
    Agence:
      foreignAlias:       Agencies
      local:              ref_agency
      foreign:            id
      class:              Agency
```

Comment: could you show us the schema ? you can use class and refClass in each relation in schema.yml to make it a one-to-many relation

Comment: thank you for your answer. The post is updated with the schema

Comment: So is Agency A, and Consultant B?  The schema doesn't match the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the plugin sfFormExtraPlugin and use the sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList:

```
 public function configure()
  {
    $this->widgetSchema['b_list']->setOption('renderer_class', 'sfWidgetFormSelectDoubleList');
  }
```

You don't need anything more.